# HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

i've got this error on my project.

HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request.

The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

InsertClient.jsp

```
<form:form action="/moldar/saveCliente/" method="POST" modelAttribute="cliente">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Pais</label> 
        <form:select path="pais" class="form-control" id="pais" name="wwww">
            <c:forEach var="lista" items="${listaPaises}">
                <option value="${lista.id}">${lista.nome}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Estado</label> 
        <form:select path="estado" class="form-control" id="estado" name="qqqqq">
            <option value="">Selecione um estado</option>
            <c:forEach var="lista" items="${listaEstados}">
                <option value="${lista.id}">${lista.nome}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Cidade</label> 
        <form:select path="cidade" class="form-control" id="cidade" name="batata">
            <option value="null">Selecione uma cidade</option>
            <c:forEach var="lista" items="${listaCidades}">
                <option value="${lista.id}">${lista.nome}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
    </div>
```

My Controllers

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveCliente", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String adicionarCliente(@ModelAttribute("cliente") Cliente cliente) {


            clienteDao.saveOrUpdate(cliente);

            return "redirect:/clientes";
        }

@RequestMapping(value = "/addCliente", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
        public String inserirCliente(Model model) {

            List<Estado> listaEstados = estadoDao.list(null);
            List<Cidade> listaCidades = cidadeDao.list(null);
            List<Pais> listaPaises = paisDao.list(null);

            model.addAttribute("listaPaises", listaPaises);
            model.addAttribute("listaEstados", listaEstados);
            model.addAttribute("pais", new Pais());
            model.addAttribute("cliente", new Cliente());
            model.addAttribute("estado", new Estado());
            model.addAttribute("cidade", new Cidade());
            model.addAttribute("listaCidades", listaCidades);
            return "inserirCliente";
        }
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table (name= "clientes")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String nome;

    @Column
    private String cpf;

    @OneToOne 
    @JoinColumn (name="pais")
    private Pais pais;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="estado")
    private Estado estado;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="cidade")
    private Cidade cidade;

    @Column
    private String logradouro;

    @Column
    private String numero;

    @Column
    private String cep;

    @Column
    private String email;
```

I have trying everything.

Can someone help me ? Please ?

Comment: Will you share something about the request?

Answer (score 0):

In your Contoller this line of code

```
     public String adicionarCliente(@ModelAttribute("cliente") Cliente cliente)
```

In your **Cliente** class  the variables like **pais**

```
<form:select path="pais" class="form-control" id="pais" name="wwww">
```

you cannot bind this **path="pais"** to **Cliente** class variable **pais** , Because **pais** is not a String Type it is an Object type.

You can Create **another class** to Bind the input Selection Options to the variables.

```
class Client {
  private String pais;
  private String estado;
  private String cidade;

public String getPais() {
    return pais;
}

public void setPais(String pais) {
    this.pais = pais;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public String getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(String cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}
```

}